# Phonetic form of plural sheep

Tags: sentence-meaning

> > The past tense of the verb *hit*, as in the sentence *Yesterday you hit the ball*,
> >     and the plural of the noun *sheep* as in *The sheep are in the meadow*, show that
> >     some morphemes have no phonological shape at all. We know that hit in the
> >     above sentence is *hit + past* because of the time adverb yesterday, and we
> >     know that **sheep is the phonetic form of *sheep + plural*** because of the plural
> >     verb form are.

What does the bolded part mean? It seems to me that the author implies there are more than two pronunciation for the word "sheep", one is for the plural form of "sheep".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the jargon, but the author is not implying that there are multiple pronunciations for "sheep". With less jargon, I would write

"In the sentences above, we know that *hit* is in the past tense because of the time adverb *yesterday*, and we know that *sheep* is being used in the plural because of the plural verb form *are*."

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do sheep (plural form) and sheep(singular form) have different pronunciation? I am curious about this though I think they do not.

Comment: They are pronounced exactly the same way.